# Advice on playtester recruiting strategy for closed beta?

Tags: playtesting, beta

I am the lead programmer for a small game company working on our first release. A top down turn based historical WWII strategy game. Because our game appeals to WWII buffs and players who enjoy ‘simulation’ levels of detail we started by posting discussions of the game and invitations to the beta on WWII related sites like (WW2 Talk, The Wargamer, Axis History Forum etc.) However, we have had comparatively little response or willingness to participate in a beta from these communities.

What are some successful strategies that others in our position (small houses working on first projects) have used, or would suggest to attract and recruit beta testers?

Comment: I'd throw in a few "regular" people in the tester pool. They might not understand what the game is about, but they should at least be able to figure out how to play it. If not, you've got some design changes to make!

Comment: If you're willing to pay your testers, you could always ask if you can put up notices at the local universities black board. I'm sure some students wouldn't mind testing your game in exchange for a small investment in their education (and living expenses).